# Separating two point clouds in order to have a better linear correlation

Tags: r, math

I want to know if there is a statistical method to separate the two point clouds in order to have two linear relationships with a good fit and with a better correlation

In my example, visually the change point of the two point clouds is between point 5 and 6 for each point cloud I found a good correlation.

How to statistically justify the separation of these two point clouds based on a best linear correlation for each point cloud

Best regards

**example :**

```
    x       y
1   1.73    3.52
2   1.24    3.01
3   0.89    2.52
4   0.43    1.64
5   0.08    1.18
6   -0.18   1.03
7   -0.65   0.96
8   -1.31   0.94
9   -2.30   0.75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get possible breakpoints using the `strucchange` package:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="    x       y
1   1.73    3.52
2   1.24    3.01
3   0.89    2.52
4   0.43    1.64
5   0.08    1.18
6   -0.18   1.03
7   -0.65   0.96
8   -1.31   0.94
9   -2.30   0.75")
plot(y~x, df)
library(strucchange)
bp <- breakpoints(y~x, data=df, h=3, breaks=1)
abline(v=df$x[bp$breakpoints], col="blue")
```

Please refer to the [Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html) and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for the mathematical/statistical background.

Comment: Thank you very much this is a very effective method